# Unable to create new project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to create a new Project in Eclipse Mars Version, a new folder is created  but JRE System library is not being added.Can any one please help.

Java Version - 1.7.0_51.

[image: Screen Shot of Error]

Comment: just give the JRE path in setting

Comment: What did you specify for the JRE in the 'Create a Java Project' wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

- After launching Eclipse IDE, right-click on a Java project and select `Properties`
- Select `Java Build Path` from `Properties for Java Project`.
- Now go to Libraries Tab and choose `Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Next -> Installed JREs`.
- Click on `Add -> Standard VM -> Next -> Directory`.
- Choose the `JRE directory`(C:\Program Files\java\JRE for windows) now and click `Finish -> Apply -> Close`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change setting of a  list of available compilers in the

**Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's tab.**

In the project build path configuration dialog, in libraries tab, you can delete the entry for *JRE System Library*, click on *Add Library* and choose the installed JRE to compile with.

Note that you should have JRE installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following this tutorial?

https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-3.htm

If you have, please provide the steps you have done until now, so the community can be more helpful.